# How do I set up the equation of a periodic function?

Tags: periodic-functions

I have a graph, and by looking at it I can see that the amplitude is 1, the maximum is 1, minimum is 0, and the period is 2. How do I set up the equation? What is the formula?

Comment: What is the shape? Is it a sine wave? A triangular wave? Square wave? Something else?

Comment: Its two straight lines that goes through the points (0,1),(1,0) and (1,0),(2,1). So a triangular wave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $f(x) = -x +1, x\in[0,1]$ and $f(x) = x-1, x\in[1,2)$

Add that $f$ is $p=2$ periodic and there is your function.

Comment: @mangekyou in this kind of problem you "cut" the function into intervals on which the definition is clear to you. This is also how these functions are defined.

Comment: @mangekyou also please use latex in comments as well, use $ signs

Comment: I'm supposed to do it using the two point formula. How do I use the two point formula to set up the equation of a periodic function?

Comment: @mangekyou what do you mean with two point formula? Is it a formula used to derive a linear function's definition from two points? If so: take the first two and the second two points, use the formula on each and that is exactly what you end up with.

Comment: I got it now thanks.

Comment: @mangekyou then please close the question :)